# How to check if the file type is CSV in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have this import button component in my project.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import Button from "@/components/base/Button"

const ButtonImport = ({ onUploadFile, loading }) => {
  const fileInput = useRef(null)
  const handleClick = event => {
    fileInput.current.value = null
    fileInput.current.click()
  }
  const handleFileChange = event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    onUploadFile(file)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        icon="upload"
        text="Upload"
        variant="line"
        size="large"
        custom="rounded-full font-extrabold"
        iconColor="fill-current text-base-orange"
        onClick={handleClick}
        loading={loading}
      />
      <input
        ref={fileInput}
        id="import-csv"
        type="file"
        accept=".csv"
        className="hidden"
        onChange={handleFileChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default ButtonImport
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And I called it like this.

```
<ButtonImport
  loading={isImportLoading}
  onUploadFile={handleUploadFile}
/>
```

With the handle function as this,

```
  const handleUploadFile = file => {
    if (file && file.type === "text/csv") {
      showModal("upload")
    } else {
      showModal("importFileInvalid")
    }
  }
```

My client has issue which handleUploadFile return `showModal("importFileInvalid")` even though the file extension is csv. Do you have any idea where is the wrong part? Thanks

Comment: Try to see what `file` actually is in `handleUploadFile`, put a breakpoint or `console.log(file)` at the top of this function. That might provide you some clues.

Comment: I see. But, the problem is happened on my client device. When I check on my device, there is no problem. So, I have no idea how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @aksal If the client is comfortable with it, I would suggest asking them to send over the file so you can upload yourself and see what's going wrong. ☺️

Comment: @JamesWilliam that's great . i like it